# JQuery - use .closest with document.getElementById()

Tags: jquery, getelementbyid, closest

Hey guys I have the following jQuery:

```
var $this   = $(this);
$this.closest('ul').find('li').removeClass('selected');
```

and I'm trying to do the same thing to an element with a similar ID by setting the variable:

```
var liID = $this.closest('li').attr('id');
var liID = liID.substring(0, liID.length - 1);
```

and then trying to call `.closest('ul').find('li').removeClass('selected');` on it. I've tried this:

```
document.getElementById(liID).closest('ul').find('li').removeClass('selected');
```

and this:

```
liID.closest('ul').find('li').removeClass('selected');
```

I'm not surprised the second didn't work, but I can't figure out how to make the first one work. Any suggestions?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As you have ID, Directly use

```
$("#" + liID).closest('ul').find('li').removeClass('selected');
```

`document.getElementById(liID)` will return a DOM element. To use jQuery method you have to convert it into jQuery object. You may try

```
$(document.getElementById(liID)).closest('ul').find('li').removeClass('selected');
```

Comment: The second one does work, but the first is much cleaner. I'll award you the answer when the time limit is up.

Answer (score 1):

`document.getElementById(liID)` returns a dom element reference which does not have jQuery related methods, so you need to get the jQuery object for that element to use jQuery methods.

You can use id-selector to get the target element then use the `closest()`

```
$('#'+liID).closest('ul').find('li').removeClass('selected');
```

Answer (score 1):

`document.getElementByID()` return a DOM element.

To use closet you want a jquery object so wrap `document.getElementByID()` with $ to make it a jquery object.

It will work